# Do we have method to display different amout of view in different phones

Tags: android, gridview

I have a tablet and a phone. Can I show 2*3 in the tablet and 2*2 in the phone properly. The activity only contains a gridview.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear.  There are fragments which can be used to make/run many different sizes.of views fornyour application.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen inches using some code. So you can separate tab and phone.

```
String inputSystem;
inputSystem = android.os.Build.ID;
Log.d("hai",inputSystem);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
Log.d("hai",width+"");
Log.d("hai",height+"");
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
double x = Math.pow(width/dm.xdpi,2);
double y = Math.pow(height/dm.ydpi,2);
double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
Log.d("hai","Screen inches : " + screenInches+"");
```